# how to know which browser my .net application is running on?

Tags: c#, .net, browser, safari

I want to apply different css on different browsers.

I want to run one css when it is safari and second for all others.

How can I detect that and apply css according to that?

Comment: When you say "my .net application", are you referring to ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS browser selectors for this. There are different solutions available for this on the net.

For example:

[CSS Browser Selector](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/)

The CSS Browser Selector is a small JavaScript library which allows you to include different cascading style sheets (CSS) for each browser.

An example:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ie .example {
    background-color: yellow
}
.ie7 .example {
    background-color: orange
}
.opera .example {
    background-color: green
}
.webkit .example {
    background-color: black
</style>
```

If you Google for "different css per browser" you'll find other solutions as well, but most of them boil down to similar solutions.

Another way would be to detect the browser type and capabilities in ASP.NET so that you can render the appropriate HTML / CSS / ...etc. You can find more information on that topic here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx

For example:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;
    string s = "Browser Capabilities\n"
        + "Type = "                    + browser.Type + "\n"
        + "Name = "                    + browser.Browser + "\n"
        + "Version = "                 + browser.Version + "\n"
        + "Major Version = "           + browser.MajorVersion + "\n"
        + "Minor Version = "           + browser.MinorVersion + "\n"
        + "Platform = "                + browser.Platform;

    TextBox1.Text = s;
}
```

The Browser property of the Request returns a HttpBrowserCapabilities object. It contains information on the capabilities of the browser that is running on the client.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilities.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can examine the `UserAgent` property of the `Request` object.

Inside the page head tag

```
<%# Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("safari") ?
    "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='safari.css' />" :
    "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='other.css' />" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below things....in your control...and you can set different style...to asp.net textbox control for different browser.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TestTextBox" runat="server" ie:Text="You are in Internet explorer."  mozilla:Text="You are in Firefox." Text="You are in other browser." ie:CssClass="IEStyle"  mozilla:CssClass="FFStyle" CssClass="DefaultStyle" />
```

Answer (score 0):

using Using the `Request.Browser` you can determine the browser user is using your

Answer (score 0):

You can check it from javascript like:

```
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
                var fileref = document.createElement("link")
                fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
                fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
            }
```